# Use of “the” in “the chess of which he was so fond”

Tags: definite-article

> Those were his last games of the chess of which he was so
>   fond.  <sub>*[source](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00B3GMN2I)*</sub>

I think it should be, "Those were his last games of chess. He was fond
of it."

What I find so strange is this "the" because chess is the name of a table game.

Answer (score 6):

Ordinarily you would be quite right: in most circumstances we would not use the article.

> These were his last games of <s>the</s> chess.

What calls for the article in this case is the relative clause which modifies *chess*—specifically, the fact that the clause is employed *restrictively*.

That is, the author might have written this:

> Those were his last games of chess, of which he was very fond.

In this example the comma (which is not ‘mechanical’ but actually represents a different intonation) marks what follows as a *non-restrictive* clause: a ‘parenthetical’ addition or afterthought.

But that is not what the author wants to say. The player’s fondness for the game is central to the author’s meaning: his purpose is to communicate that these games marked the end of an activity which was important for the player.

Instead, the author casts the relative as a *restrictive* clause; and in its ordinary use, a restrictive clause has to modify a definite NP. In fact, the restriction in sense *makes* the NP it modifies definite.

Granted, this is not the ordinary use of a restrictive clause, which in most cases acts to ‘carve out’ one or more specific members of a larger class. The restrictive clause is used here to ‘carve out’ a specific aspect of the game: the player’s fondness for it. But the syntactical rules don’t know this is a different use; all they know is “Restrictive clause?—gotta have a determiner!” So *the* is inserted. This is purely conventional—I imagine that *the* is employed rather than *a*, which would also work, simply because *chess* has been mentioned before in the source passage.

Note that the author might also have written something like this:

> These were his last games of his beloved chess.

—and there, too, we have a determiner, *his*.

Comment: @username901345 I've been thinking about this on the drive in to work, and I've made some changes, which may address your confusion. But the key point is that **that is how we say it**. That’s the idiom. It confuses you because you haven’t encountered this use before, and you’re trying to fit it into other uses. But it’s a different use, and it won’t fit. The ‘meaning’ of *the* (which as I am sure you know is a very loosely used word anyway!) doesn’t come into it.

Comment: @username901345 I don't think _a_ could be put before chess and retain the same emphasis. As you said, there is only one chess. And saying _a chess of which he was so fond_ robs chess of its specificity. Nor does any previous mention of chess in the passage have anything to do with the choice of _the._ I'm thinking specificity might be a key to the use of _the._ We can even use this construction with a person. _That is the Harvey of which we are so fond._ Not _That is a Harvey of which we are so fond._ _A_ Harvey? _A_ chess? No, specificity and emphasis requires _the._

Comment: @StoneyB I find this very informative. Is this "the" of "hell" the same as this "the" discussed here? This is from the Spider Thread:" If it were to break midway, then Kandata himself would plummet back down into the Hell he had struggled so mightily to escape."

Comment: @StoneyB PLeas!

Comment: @user08742 That is right, the same *the*.

Comment: @StoneyB Thank you. So I could say, If someone believes in logic strongly, "I believe in the logic you believe in, too" to mean not any specific cases of logic but "logic" in general? like "I believe in logic" ?

Comment: @user08742 Yes - that would be equivalent to "I believe in the same logic you believe in".